# How to use a callback function to jump out of a method?

Tags: c#

I have method which makes a couple of web requests. If the first request meets a specific condition, the method should return the result immediately so that the process continues. However, the method should proceed further to the end.

This is main loop:

```
await Task.Run(() => 
{
    while (true)
    {
        var data = MakeRequest(worker1);

        if (worker2 != null)
            data = MakeRequest(worker2);

        ProcessData(data);
    }
});

private SomeData MakeRequest(Worker worker)
{
    //Make first request

    //If results meet specific condition, return them at this point

    //Second request must always be executed
}
```

Is it possible to return back to the main method so that `worker2` can make the request, whilst the `MakeRequest` call for `worker1` still executes but afterwards?

Comment: sounds like you need another thread

Comment: You are going to want to write a `MakeRequestAsync` method that returns a task.  This may involve dispatching work to a thread, but you might also have some naturally occurring asnyc-ness you could rely upon.  You are also probably want to change your logic, if both `MakeRequestAsync` calls are running at the same time, don't assign the results of both of them to `data` (which you are then going to _Process_.  That would be an obvious race (with the last guy to finish winning).

Comment: It's unclear right now what you're trying to synchronize between the two calls.  Are you trying to process the data from the first call while making the second call and then process the data from the second call before making any more calls?  As @pm100 said you'll need to use another thread to do that but exactly how depends on how you're trying to coordinate everything.